# Linux LoginServer

Tags: login, ldap, remote-desktop

I want a Linux server with the user accounts.

The users will see a login screen after boot. So they can directly login on the server without noticing it.

The user folders are also saved there, like in some school systems.

Can you please give me a tutorial how to set it up?

The server is a Raspbian and the clients will be on Mint.

Can you please help me? I can't find anything on the web.

Comment: You have to give some performance figures. What software should run on the clients, what kind of computers are the clients and the server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are requiring an LDAP server with client login to authenticate. Your post is not clear whether the clients will be running Linux, however this answer will assume that you they are.

LDAP stands for Lightweight Directory Access Protocol. This allows access to authentication, accessing directory services and user management over a network.

This setup would allow you once configured, to have client computers directly connect to the LDAP server for authentication from any client on the network without needing a local account on the client.

OpenLDAP is an open source client server application that can be configured on Raspbien. https://www.openldap.org/ is the link to the OpenLDAP project.

A search for “ldap raspbien” will provide an array of articles to guide you through setup:
http://blog.crazypi.com/install-configure-basic-ldap-server-raspberry-pi/
https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-LDAP-Server/

Comment: thanks for the links! But they only show how to install the server, i also need to login from the clients

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/configure-ldap-client-to-connect-external-authentication/ This seems like a pretty decent client for setting up clients.